# Getting nullpointer exceptions when turning back to application

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-resources

I have a MainActivity. This MainActivity contains a TabLayout with Fragments. I am calling from the MainActivity functions in the Fragment when for example the user changed a tab.

Everything works fine so far. However, when the application is not in front and when it resumes, and the same functions are called again, I get often nullpointer exceptions. It seems like the objects created in OnCreateView are destroyed?

What is best practise in this situation?

Comment: Do you create fragments with non-empty constructors? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your app comes to foreground from background, sometime the activity might have been killed and system create another instance of it with the bundle you pass in onSaveInstanceState. So, the activity instance, fragment was attached is destroyed and this is new instance, which is not aware of the fragment.

You need to verify the fragment state with fragment.isAdded() and fragment isVisible() before adding or removing fragments to Activity. Probably there you might have getting null pointer exceptions. Hope it helps.